# Как скопировать файлы с сервера на сервер

Tags: debian, centos

Нужно скопировать файлы с сервера на centos на сервер с debian, ssh есть на debian
Задал аналогичный вопрос на руткоде, но там очень тихо..
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А исходящем серваке таришь все в один файл, На входяшем серваке делаешь fetch или wget. Затем растариваешь

Comment: Вариант ) но хотелось бы что то вроде 
>scp -p -r /home/user/dir root@12.12.12.12:/home/newuser/dir/on/remote/server - копирует файлы или каталоги с одного сервера на другой

Comment: А в чем проблема?))))

Comment: В том. что у меня нет ssh на centos (на сервере, с которого будем копировать), зато есть права на сервере, НА который будем копировать :) тыкать  (менять местами)мне стремно, хочется услышать ответ профессионалов

Comment: Ну если нет ssh, то ничто вам не поможет кроме ftp... иначе как Вы будете коннектиться к серваку?

на центосе есть хотябы фтп-сервер?

Если есть фтп-сервер и доступ, то так же в mc делаете FTP link вместо SSH link, как писал ниже.

Comment: Да, ftp есть, видимо сделаю wget затаренный )

Comment: Если нет ssh, не сможешь затарить)))

Answer (score 1):

Что Вам мешает использовать команду scp?
Ну или ftp-менеджер, но по 22му порту используя ssl?(тут могу неслабо гнать, лично не пользовался)

Comment: Ничего не мешает. Если во фри я знаю пару тройку команд, в частности команду для копирования файлов / каталогов с одного сервера на другой, то в дебиане я почти ничего не знаю

Comment: Так делайте scp, не вижу проблемы :)

Answer (score 0):

конектишся по ssh, после от имени админа sudo mc ну или nautilus. копируешь в директорию юзера под которым законектился.

Comment: Это если есть права рута и на серваке установлен тот же наутилус. К слову, обычно админы запрещают вход рута по ssh...

Comment: Права рута есть на дебиане, там же есть и ssh, можно подробнее?

Comment: запускаешь mc. Делаешь ssh коннект в mc на другой сервер, копируешь F5-том... как в менеджере

Comment: Если есть права, тогда запускаешь менеджера (sudo mc) ну и копируй все через менеджера в директорию пользователя /home/usr/user_name